# Разное поведение простых вещей в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvBVRq

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #wrapper {
 height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
}

#left {
  padding: 55px;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #474747;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="runeword-item">
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div class="lvl">bal bal 1</div>
      <div class="sockets">bla bla 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="runeword-item">
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div class="lvl">bal bal 2</div>
      <div class="sockets">bla bla 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="runeword-item">
      <div>Item 3</div>
      <div>Item 3</div>
      <div class="lvl">bal bal 3</div>
      <div class="sockets">bla bla 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="runeword-item">
      <div>Item 4</div>
      <div>Item 4</div>
      <div class="lvl">bal bal 4</div>
      <div class="sockets">bla bla 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="runeword-item">
      <div>Item 5</div>
      <div>Item 5</div>
      <div class="lvl">bal bal 5</div>
      <div class="sockets">bla bla 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">123456789</div>
</div>
```

В chrome отображается все как нужно, но в mozilla firefox, ie и edge, нету нижнего padding у id="left"...

Почему так происходит, это баг mozilla firefox, ie и edge, или просто я что то не так сделал?

Comment: Подключение [reset.css](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/reset-css) позволит вам избавиться от предустановленных браузерных стилей (ибо они могу быть различными) и уровнять начальный вид страницы.

Comment: @Deliaz, пробовал подключать и `Reset CSS` и `Normalize CSS`, не помогает...

Comment: В Firefox и Edge padding есть.

Comment: @E_K `нижнего` padding

Comment: @E_K нижнего — нету. Я сам на эту проблему натыкался, когда один из своих сайтов делал (правда, решать её не стал)

Comment: Нижний паддинг есть. Вы думаете, его нету, потому что скролл не появляется, когда должен?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, запустите в хроме и в мозиле, прокрутите в самый низ, и в хроме есть нижний паддинг в 55 пикселей, а в мозиле его нету...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko что значит «скролл не появляется»? В этом примере есть скролл всегда в любом браузере. А вот нижний паддинг есть не везде

Comment: @andreymal, я уже придумал пару трюков(может даже костылей), что бы решить эту проблему, например не паддинг родительскому давать а маргин дочерним, или добавить афтер в родительский... Но интересно почему такое происходит...

Comment: @andreymal Вы, надеюсь, видете знак вопроса в том предложении? Значит, это вопрос. Значит, я не уверен и спрашиваю.

Comment: Так как вы определили, что паддинга нету? У меня в хроме и мозиле он есть.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko покажите скриншот с нижним паддингом из Firefox, пожалуйста?

Comment: @andreymal Хром http://prntscr.com/ji3e10. Обратите внимание на скролл. Появление скролла происходит с учетом нижнего паддинга. Файрфокс http://prntscr.com/ji3fhw. Обратите внимание опять же на скролл. Появление скролла происходит без учета нижнего паддинга. Но паддинг есть.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko паддинг видно только в инструментах разработчика, а конечный пользователь его не видит (текст налезает на фиолетовую подсвеченную область), поэтому можно считать, что фактически паддинга нет — в этом и суть вопроса: почему не как в хроме и как сделать как в хроме

Comment: @andreymal Вы же понимаете, что правильно заданный вопрос - уже 50% ответа. Надо понять, что именно не так, и потом будет легче разибраться. Суть в том, что паддинг есть. Ведь проблема не в том, что *нету нижнего padding у id="left"*, а в том, почему при переполнении контента нижний паддинг не учитывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding на самом деле есть и работает исправно. проверить это можно, если создать внутри `#left` элемент, который займет всю высоту.

Пример.  Смотреть на полной странице.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  padding: 55px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#leftwrapper{
  background-color:red;
  height:100%;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #474747;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="leftwrapper">
      <div class="runeword-item">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div class="lvl">bal bal 1</div>
        <div class="sockets">bla bla 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="runeword-item">
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div class="lvl">bal bal 2</div>
        <div class="sockets">bla bla 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="runeword-item">
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div class="lvl">bal bal 3</div>
        <div class="sockets">bla bla 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="runeword-item">
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div class="lvl">bal bal 4</div>
        <div class="sockets">bla bla 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="runeword-item">
        <div>Item 5</div>
        <div>Item 5</div>
        <div class="lvl">bal bal 5</div>
        <div class="sockets">bla bla 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">123456789</div>
</div>
```

Другое дело, что появление скролла работает по разному. В хроме нижний паддинг считается за контент, в мозиле не считается.

Решение, как вы сами написали в комментариях - использовать `margin` или пустой элемент - смотря по ситуации.

Comment: а это вполне логичное объяснение, но не такое очевидное (как хотелось бы)... но от него больше вопросов.. в духе: почему такая несогласованность в подходах обработки контента?

Comment: @Руслан Это вы сафари откройте - там еще больше не согласованности найдете) Мир не совершенен, разные люди понимают и делают по разному. Хотя интересно было бы найти, что по этому поводу говорит стандарт.

Comment: не могу, у меня нету техники Apple